# Spring Boot can't receive POST from JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I want to POST some data to the back end so I used jQuery:

```
<section>
    <script>    
        $("#score").click(function () {
            var usual = $(".usual").val();
            var final = $(".final").val();
            var total = $(".total").val();
            var student = $("#student").text();
            $.post("/teacher/students/score",{"student":student,"usual":usual,"final":final,"total":total},function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
</section>
```

I wrote a controller:

```
@PostMapping("/teacher/students/score")
public void score(@RequestParam(name = "id") String student,
                  @RequestParam(name = "usual") int usualScore,
                  @RequestParam(name = "final") int finalScore,
                  @RequestParam(name = "total") int totalScore,
                  HttpSession session,
                  HttpServletResponse response){

    //process data...
}
```

But when I clicked the button in the page, nothing happened in backend. It seemed that the controller couldn't receive the POST request from jQuery. Can anyone help?
------------------------UPDATE--------------------------
I used Chrome's developer tool and then I found that the status code was 400. Maybe this is the actual reason?

Answer (score 0):

In controller, `Post` method expect `required query parameter` but you pass request body from jquery. If you want to specify  query param in post method from jquery then use  `jQuery.param`.

Try with this:

```
$.post(url: "/teacher/students/score",
       data: jQuery.param({"student":student,"usual":usual,"final":final,"total":total},function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
```

Comment: you use thymeleaf?

Comment: check jquery add your application context path wit /teacher/students/score

Comment: yeah I use thymeleaf

Comment: <script th:inline="javascript"> add this?

Comment: otherwise context path not add in your request

Comment: Ok I'll add <script th:inline="javascript"> and have a try. But I've found that the status code is 400. Is this the reason actually?

Comment: 400 means not fond

Comment: Check which url called